# Showing a curve is a variety (example)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am working on Exercise 2.8 of Fulton's book on Algebraic Curves.

Briefly, it asks to show $V = V(XZ-Y^2, YZ-X^3,Z^2-X^2Y)$ is a variety over $\mathbb{C}$.

I tried using the hint there. We define $W = V(Y^3-X^4, Z^3-X^5, Z^4-X^5)$ so that $I(W) \subseteq I(V)$. Then we have a map $A^1(\mathbb{C}) \to W$ given by $t \mapsto (t^{15}, t^{20}, t^{12})$. By another exercise, this implies $W$ is irreducible because the preimage under this map is irreducible ($A^1$). But I can't seem to translate this into information about $V$ because although $I(W) \subseteq I(V)$, this need not imply $I(V)$ is prime (like $(0) \subset (p^2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$).

Could anyone provide a useful hint on how to proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: I think the hint is there to help you realize that $V$ is given by the image of $t \mapsto (t^{3},t^{4},t^{5})$.

Comment: Oh, I don't know how I missed that! Thanks!